# grep multiple strings, count lines, echo output for each string

Tags: grep

I have a directory of files that is structured like this:

```
data/directory1/file1.xml
data/directory2/file2.xml
data/directory3/file3.xml
...
```

There are thousands of sub directories within data/, each with one xml file.

I would like to recursively scan data/ and look for three patterns, then echo the count of the pattern match (ideally) with a label before each.  So, for my output, I'd like to see

```
Pattern 1 = 20
Pattern 2 = 100
Pattern 3 = 432
```

I've been able to use this to run these one at a time using:

```
grep -E -r 'Pattern 1' data/ | wc -l
grep -E -r 'Pattern 2' data/ | wc -l
grep -E -r 'Pattern 3' data/ | wc -l
```

Now I'm trying to put this all into a shell script with one argument, which would be parent directory of data/.  Then output the count to each pattern to either standard output or count.txt.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: have you check  `-c` flag to `grep` ?

Comment: Of course, `grep -c` makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

You should check `grep -c`, it does exactly what you describe. If you need more flexibility, you could probably use `awk`. Try something like this (typed directly in the browser and not tested):

```
dir=$1
# add tests to check if $1 exists (-d) and/or is non null (-n)

find "${dir}" | awk <<\EOF

BEGIN {
   pat1 = 0;
   pat2 = 0;
   ...
}

/pattern/ { pat1 += 1;}
/otherpattern/ {pat2 += 2;}
...

END {
   print "pattern", pat1;
   print "otherpattern", pat2;
   ...
}
EOF
```

I'll leave it up to you to work out the details of the `find` command or the `awk` script.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I know nothing about `awk` so this is entirely new territory. I guess I was hoping the `for` loop would work and I wouldn't have to use something like `awk`.

Comment: Of course the `for` loop can work. Try this `for pat in 'pat1' 'pat2' 'pat3'; do echo $pat $(grep -E -rc "$pat" $1); done`. Depending on the version of `grep` you're using, you may need to tweak this command a (tiny) bit. I only mentioned `awk` so that you loop only once over the subdirs (in case there are too many) and you want to control the output or add some calculation. The `awk` script I wrote is somewhat incomplete but should give you an idea of how it works. Try to read it I bet you'd find out `awk` isn't as hard as it's made out to be :)

Comment: Thanks, I will do my `awk` homework :)

Comment: Trying to figure out why the `for` loop from @rahmu above doesn't work. I did: `for pat in 'text1' 'text2' 'text3';
 do echo $(grep -E -rc '$pat' $1);
done'` The result is something like this for every file in the directory (there are thousands): "/data/dir1/file:0".  What I am expecting is "text1=10, text2=20, text3=32".  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The following script loops over the pattern and prints the total count of matches for each pattern. It searches under the directory whose name is passed as an argument, or under the current directory if you don't pass an argument.

```
#!/bin/sh
for p in 'Pattern 1' 'Pattern 2' 'Pattern 3; do
  printf '%s = ' "$p"; grep -E -r -e "$p" "${1:-.}/data" | wc -l
done
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you! I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation points :).  Can you explain this `${1:-.}` a little?  I understand that it is the variable from the arguement, but what does `:-` do?

Comment: @karavan: This is the syntax for defining a default value. If `$1` is empty (if no command line arguments are supplied), then use to value `.`. `man bash` and a quick search of `:-` would explain it best.